# How to use kmeans to sort out the shadow in OpenCV

Tags: opencv

I am using OpenCV for the shadow detection, and trying to remove the shadow. I have tried to use the HSV space to distinguish the shadow from the car, but it doesn't work well. So I am think if it is good to use kmeans to sort out the shadow and how to do it in OpenCV.

[image]

Comment: I have no idea how k-means should be applied to this problem. Can you maybe clarify question? I also fixed caps and other stuff like this. Please try to find time do it yourself next time.

Answer (score 1):

You can find the details in this paper: http://thesai.org/Downloads/Volume4No1/Paper_26-Shadow_Suppression_using_RGB_and_HSV_Color_Space_in_Moving_Object_Detection.pdf